# MongoDB simple geoWithin query takes 10 minutes on 3M documents

Tags: mongodb

I've got a MongoDB with two collections of tweets, one in Pittsburgh (`tweet_pgh`), ~3M tweets, and one in Cleveland (`tweet_cleveland`), ~160k tweets. In each city, I've been trying to run a small $geoWithin query, like so:

```
db.tweet_cleveland.find({coordinates: {$geoWithin: {$geometry:
    {type : "Polygon", coordinates : [ [ [ -81.6826, 41.5041 ], [ -81.6726, 41.5041 ], [ -81.6726, 41.4941 ], [ -81.6826, 41.5041 ] ] ] }}
}}).explain()
```

No problem. Finishes in 251ms, scans 13k documents, returns ~2k documents.

```
{
    "cursor" : "S2Cursor",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 2070,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2070,
    "nscanned" : 13874,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2070,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 13874,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 4,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 251,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "nscanned" : 13874,
    "matchTested" : NumberLong(11804),
    "geoTested" : NumberLong(11804),
    "cellsInCover" : NumberLong(2),
    "server" : ...
}
```

So I try to do the same in Pittsburgh, which has ~20 times as many tweets, and assume it'll take ~20x as long, so 5000ms.

```
db.tweet_pgh.find({coordinates: {$geoWithin: {$geometry:
    {type : "Polygon", coordinates : [ [ [ -79.940, 40.466 ], [ -79.940, 40.465 ], [ -79.943, 40.465 ], [ -79.940, 40.466 ] ] ] }}
}}).explain()
```

But it takes about 10 minutes. (2000 times as long.)

```
{
    "cursor" : "S2Cursor",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 2129,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2129,
    "nscanned" : 284093,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2129,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 284093,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 3,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 586680,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "nscanned" : 284093,
    "matchTested" : NumberLong(281964),
    "geoTested" : NumberLong(281964),
    "cellsInCover" : NumberLong(1),
    "server": ...
}
```

Things I've checked: index (they both have a 2dsphere index, which is being used in both. (the cursor says "S2Cursor"). RAM (not a problem, ~3gb free). Another similar collection (tweet_sf, which has ~2M tweets, is just as slow as tweet_pgh). Similar size queries (both in size and in number of records returned)

Any ideas why it's so slow? Is there something quadratic or worse going on with geoWithin or 2dsphere indexes?
Thanks!

Edit: after fooling with it for a while, the best I can tell is that this is just a very time-consuming operation. Nothing I'm obviously doing wrong, it's just that this is hard. I'm trying to migrate to PostgreSQL + PostGIS now, which seems like it'll be faster, but no real numbers yet.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm answering my question even though I still don't know why it's slow. But I know the answer to my *real* question, which is "what should I do now?"

The answer is, migrate to Postgres/PostGIS.

Did some benchmarking: http://ilessendata.blogspot.com/2015/04/mongodb-vs-postgresql-for-geo-queries.html if you'd like to know more, but in short, it looks like geo "find everything within this box" queries are 1-2 orders of magnitude faster on Postgres (if you index and cluster by coordinates).

Good luck, future StackOverflowers who stumble over this nugget of frustration.

Comment: A thing to note: no index was used in your query.

Comment: You mean the query above here? Are you sure? I thought S2Cursor meant it was using the 2dsphere index. e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969405/why-i-make-a-2dsphere-index-but-when-i-query-it-shows-s2cursor).